# Better Than MVC Pattern

Tags: php, model-view-controller, design-patterns, frameworks

I know there has been much shout about the goodness of MVC pattern.
My question is that is there any pattern better than MVC to be
implemented in PHP?

I don't know but other pattern might have advantages over the MVC pattern.

So actually I am in search whether there is something better than MVC.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: another great answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621832/architecture-more-suitable-for-web-apps-than-mvc)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

MVC architecture is a tool for building a certain kind of app. Your question is a bit like asking if there's anything better than a screwdriver. For nailing in nails, yes, there is. For driving screws, not so much.

Answer (score 2):

There are probably many design patterns that someone may consider "better" than MVC, but I doubt you'll find something that is a *replacement* for MVC that is better in all regards.  There are other related patterns but it's all about tradeoffs.  MVC is popular for a reason.

Answer (score 2):

Typically people speak about MVC and MVP design patterns, however i like the [MVCP](http://www.martinhunter.co.nz/articles/MVPC.pdf) pattern, this has been very effective in my current project. It has enabled me to keep my code nice and clean, plus, its great pattern to ensure testability.

Even though i haven't used any existing PHP frameworks, MVPC is used in the [Microsft Web Client Software Factory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264518.aspx). Following a well established pattern will definitely help in the long run, provide the concepts of the pattern are full understood.