# What Frameworks represent a paradigm different than the MVC?

Tags: php, python, ruby, frameworks, paradigms

We hear a lot about frameworks like Django, ROR and CodeIgniter in Python, ruby and PHP respectively, all of them represents the MVC paradigm, is there other paradigm different than MVC represented with a framework?, what's the framework name, the paradigm and the differences?

Comment: Super boring topic. In PHP it's pretty much only [Lion](http://matrix.include-once.org/framework/view.php?name=lion) which officially departs from the "MVC" moniker. Not much deviation in how it's actually implemented though. Other patterns (MVP or MVVM) [might not be more applicable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1549970/345031) to the web either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all neither RoR nor CodeIgniter is implementing MVC. They are using MVP pattern .. and are pretty bad at it too ( [here is a small comment about how they are different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621832/architecture-more-suitable-for-web-apps-than-mvc/7622038#7622038) ).

Alternative paradigms are:

- [event driven programming](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?EventDrivenProgramming)
- [data, context and interaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data,_context_and_interaction) or DCI

... and there is n-Tier, but i am pretty clueless about where it stands in the pecking order.

Comment: I read here (http://andrzejonsoftware.blogspot.com/2011/09/rails-is-not-mvc.html) that Rails is Model2. Anyway, Model2 or MVP, why is it bad at it?

Comment: @tokland , it hast to do with way the data from model end up in the view. *Controller* should not be gathering data from model and passing it to template-like view, that is MVP. And they are bad at it because ORM is **not** model.

Answer (score 1):

[Lift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lift_%28web_framework%29)

from http://liftweb.net/lift_overview

> So, Lift is not just another me-too MVC framework. It's a framework
>   that's got some core design principals behind it that have matured
>   very well. It's a framework that gives the dual advantages of security
>   and developer productivity. Lift is a framework that's built in layers
>   and gives the developer the right choices based on their needs...
>   choices for view generation, choices for persistence, etc.