# is the bidirectional reference will cause the peformance issue?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

In my project,I use the mvc concept when do the UI related operation.

For example,there is a model named "Map",then there is another object "MapView" along with "Map" object.

Now I create them this way:

```
function Map(){
  //other codes.
  this.view=new MapView(this);
}


function MapView(model){
  //other code
  this.model=model;
}
```

Now both the model and view have a reference to each other.

I wonder this is the best practice?

Will this cause performance problem?

Comment: your model and your view should not have reference to eachother, depending on how you implement the MVC, your controller should be taking care of this. [take a look at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621832/architecture-more-suitable-for-web-apps-than-mvc/7622038#7622038)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong performance wise (it might slow down on IE3 or NN4 though).

However it seems bad to have a bidirectional reference from a design view point.

You may want to use reference passing instead like `MapView.render(model)`