# MVP and model-view communication

Tags: model-view-controller, mvp

First, it is already clear to me that the most important point of MVC is the separation of responsibilities. Lately I have been reading some articles/Q&A in the web to understand the differences between most popular MVC implementations. Examples:
[Architecture more suitable for web apps than MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621832/architecture-more-suitable-for-web-apps-than-mvc/7622038#7622038)
http://joel.inpointform.net/software-development/mvvm-vs-mvp-vs-mvc-the-differences-explained/

If I got it right, people say that the major difference between MVC and MVP is that there is no communication between model and view layers in MVP, controller works as a mediator between both. However, I do not see this restriction in MVP original paper: http://www.wildcrest.com/Potel/Portfolio/mvp.pdf, it just seems to add details to the MVC model, in the form of selections, commands and an interactor.

It seems to me that MVP is just an overloaded MVC acronym which may mean one of two MVC patterns: passive view or supervising controller.

Could someone clarify this?

Comment: Have you read [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056/what-are-mvp-and-mvc-and-what-is-the-difference)?

Comment: Yes, but that didnt help much. Most voted answer is confusing and all answers are quite different. I dont see a consensus.